# Bottle label with multiple texture layers

Tags: bezier-curves, shader-nodes, shrinkwrap

I'm creating a paper label on a gin bottle with multiple texture layers and need some advice on how to go about it. The layers are:

1. Paper stock with procedural bump texture using noise.
2. Black ink, can be combined with the above as the reflectivity is the same.
3. Copper foil, much more metallic and reflective so can't run through the same Principled BSDF.
4. High build varnish. Very glossy and completely transparent. A little bit of thickness.

I've had some success on the totally flat stopper label. I was able to do the ink/paper as a PNG texture then import SVG elements and stack them on top of one another as curves with different textures for the foil and high build varnish:
[image: Render of stopper label using stacked curves]

Very happy with that. Now I'm trying to get it to work on the front label. It's a rectangular label wrapping around three faces of the bottle. I've tried shrink wrapping but it doesn't seem to work on 2D curves. They crash into the corners and the linework seems to break up. I could bring them in as separate elements for this one but some of the other bottles have art wrapping around the corners. Furthermore, manually positioning each layer for each label on each bottle seems very inefficient.

Here's a failure:
[image: Eevee preview of attempt to shrink wrap curves onto the label]

Converting curves to meshes results in meshes full of skinny triangles very close together. I seem to recall I'll need a nice quad grid to shrink wrap nicely. I tried solidify then re-mesh modifiers but it always comes out with blocky edges.

Next I tried stacking PNG textures and setting the alpha of the copper foil to the alpha from the PNG. Each of the black ink/paper and foil textures looks great by itself but when I merge them with a Mix Shader, it seems to cross fade between them rather than stacking them like layers in Photoshop. It also feels like it's struggling to do it. I'm also not sure how I'd make the high build varnish would work using this approach:
[image: Screenshot of shader nodes and the outcome.]

Yes, the UV mapping is misaligned. This was a quick test.

Ultimately I like the idea of sticking with curves like the stopper label. Most of the label artwork is vector (Illustrator) and if I can get it working I'll have quite a few versions to import.

Question in short: do I keep trying to mix raster textures using multiple shaders or go back and try to figure out how to wrap curves around a 3D surface? Or is there some way I could apply curves like a UV texture? Or some other method that would be much more appropriate?

All of the other examples I've found so far aren't quite the solution.

Comment: On the top of the bottle, that label should be converted into an actual texture (i.e. creating roughness maps, alpha maps, and normal maps.) Perhaps this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GItohAbyzCM

Comment: Thanks for that, I might try it in the future on another project. Too bad that's a Windows-only tool. I'm happy with the existing procedural approach for the label's paper texture. It's real enough and let's me zoom in as much as I like.

Comment: Shoot. Sorry! I didn't know you had a mac!